# My icons aren't properly loading

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I currently work on a C#/asp.net project, and my icons are not displayed correctly any more. I say "any more" because at a moment, it worked. That lead me to think that it's not a problem of importation, but more of code (but I may be wrong). The used icons come from the libraries "font awesome" and "ionicons". As I am a newbie in HTML, I really don't know where the problem could come from : I put here the code of the html page which could be incriminated, but I am not really sure it's relevant.

```
@model Serene5.Common.DashboardPageModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Dashboard";
    ViewData["PageId"] = "Dashboard";
}

@section Head {
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/iCheck/flat/blue.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Scripts/morris/morris.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Scripts/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap-1.2.2.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Scripts/datepicker/datepicker3.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Scripts/daterangepicker/daterangepicker-bs3.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Scripts/bootstrap-wysihtml5/bootstrap3-wysihtml5.min.css">
<script src="~/Scripts/raphael/raphael-min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/morris/morris.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/sparkline/jquery.sparkline.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap-1.2.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap-world-mill-en.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/knob/jquery.knob.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/daterangepicker/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap-wysihtml5/bootstrap3-wysihtml5.all.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/adminlte/pages/dashboard.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/adminlte/demo.js"></script>
}

@section ContentHeader {
    <h1>@LocalText.Get("Navigation.Dashboard")<small>@Html.Raw(Texts.Site.Dashboard.ContentDescription)</small></h1>
}

<div class="row">
    <!-- Small boxes (Stat box) -->
    @{for (int i = 0; i < Model.ListStations.Length; i++)
        {
            string urlTemp = Model.ListStations[i];
            string colorTemp = "small-box bg-" + Model.ListColors[i % Model.ListColors.Length];


            <div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-6">
                <!-- small box -->
                <!-- achtung hier soll man vielleicht die Adresse ändern -->



                <div class="@colorTemp">
                    <div class="inner">
                        <h3>Station</h3>
                        <p> @Model.ListStations[i]</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="icon">
                        <i class="ion ion-stats-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </div>
                    <a href=@urlTemp class="small-box-footer">More info <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>
                </div>;

            </div>
        <!-- /.row -->
        }
    }
</div>
<!-- Main row -->
<div class="row">
    <!-- Left col -->
    <section class="col-lg-7 connectedSortable">
        <!-- Custom tabs (Charts with tabs)-->
        <div class="nav-tabs-custom">
            <!-- Tabs within a box -->
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs pull-right">
                <li class="active"><a href="#revenue-chart" data-toggle="tab">Area</a></li>
                <li><a href="#sales-chart" data-toggle="tab">Donut</a></li>
                <li class="pull-left header"><i class="fa fa-inbox"></i> Sales</li>
            </ul>
            <div class="tab-content no-padding">
                <!-- Morris chart - Sales -->
                <div class="chart tab-pane active" id="revenue-chart" style="position: relative; height: 300px;"></div>
                <div class="chart tab-pane" id="sales-chart" style="position: relative; height: 300px;"></div>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /.nav-tabs-custom -->
    </section><!-- right col -->
</div><!-- /.row (main row) -->
```

Here is also a screen showing how the website is currently displayed

[image: The website <3]

Don't hesitate to ask for any further details, I will edit the post

Here is the html generated by the page :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<!--[if IE 8]> <html lang="en-US" class="ie8 no-js"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]> <html lang="en-US" class="ie9 no-js"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]><!-->
<html lang="en-US" class="no-js">
<!--<![endif]-->
<head>

<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
<link rel="home" id="ApplicationPath" href="/" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
    <link href="/Content/font-open-sans.css?v=_lyM_7sDAZstbPZ6aTr8rQ2" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

    <link href="/Content/font-awesome.css?v=xJVlSGl4W8PfYCFmFoFK0Q2" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

    <link href="/Content/simple-line-icons.css?v=CTymYjlO1pj9tYNeQl0o3Q2" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

    <link href="/Content/ionicons.css?v=8nNUsorzz0jSgmDAMwXQzg2" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

    <link href="/Content/aristo/aristo.css?v=MvOjKTOOh8qSpUV6_HAAHw2" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

    <link href="/Content/bootstrap.css?v=KjHcoRLyaSO1FnbLdkxY1Q2" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

    <link href="/Content/colorbox/jquery.colorbox.css?v=XnRFE7k2jxZ7HVn-r2Jaww2" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

    <link href="/Content/jquery.fileupload.css?v=T6JqyTNuIq_tJ7F3R_5z3g2" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

    <link href="/Content/pace.css?v=L_wBl1JNKiTT55UKpioDig2" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

    <link href="/Content/slick.grid.css?v=Qhl0MYjRyBVihAtJg0CyYg2" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

    <link href="/Content/css/select2.css?v=qz1jk8aVr8t_14LSWpFqJA2" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

    <link href="/Content/toastr.css?v=lykj60CDw5t8wg1dl5y0OA2" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

    <link href="/Content/serenity/serenity.css?v=gXaUzPFBrbwXSSXwdXa1Dw2" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

    <link href="/Content/site/site.css?v=9m22h6rQgsGBXJmC3nRqDw2" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>


<script type="application/json" id="ScriptCulture">{"DateOrder":"mdy","DateFormat":"MM/dd/yyyy","DateSeparator":"/","DateTimeFormat":"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss","DecimalSeparator":".","GroupSepearator":","}</script>
<script type="text/javascript">window.paceOptions = { minTime: 250, ghostTime: 250, restartOnRequestAfter: 250, ajax: { trackMethods: ['GET', 'POST'], trackWebSockets: true, ignoreURLs: [] } };</script>
    <script src="/Scripts/pace.js?v=evfXQgyADGar15z3wQSTJA2" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="/Scripts/rsvp.js?v=ueGo_q7N2s93Y-AzfUrs8A2" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.js?v=RoNrvGA8lWW1zAYRAMy6yA2" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.js?v=q1KE3l49Ih5TZH_TSOVkSw2" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-i18n.js?v=fAmmyIS6gdv3hjEK_SFl9Q2" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.js?v=Q3Q3qwsR7Ja623fum9IuDw2" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.blockUI.js?v=pK0cWqNrGE32YMv5pAHwjQ2" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.cookie.js?v=1VKN3gAGx4vgSBcyfC-bbw2" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.json.js?v=ojEuMerciKpf9J0ukgaNyg2" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.autoNumeric.js?v=Cx_a1fBvtVV4DjFAtii2Yw2" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.colorbox.js?v=lWVLMExZxFAtnKWbSFmEUQ2" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.dialogextendQ.js?v=q4CdCMYs_hImIJk7B7KATg2" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.event.drag.js?v=Q42_cWjms19Czv7rSFThUg2" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.scrollintoview.js?v=j4tgWM1381VKsGUok8so9w2" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/select2.js?v=mb-susqgC8W2T0C4V7rb5g2" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/sortable.js?v=BBvydRU72CWAGeMpFpM-_Q2" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/toastr.js?v=gOnkqpQBPIBBWDh-h2vjsg2" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/SlickGrid/slick.core.js?v=BLCRBDx7U3jsEuDNgnEQkw2" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/SlickGrid/slick.grid.js?v=f5lvq3M8mdFxwZoSgj7E8w2" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/SlickGrid/slick.groupitemmetadataprovider.js?v=RUFU1x9TDSkyvChFWteLsA2" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/SlickGrid/Plugins/slick.autotooltips.js?v=-AIKLINWiZmkA-CnhA5ZRQ2" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/SlickGrid/Plugins/slick.headerbuttons.js?v=9YOWFAIrd9_PYSbDwFxdqg2" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.js?v=-4FUnuKJZROh7VcUsbGg8A2" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/saltarelle/mscorlib.js?v=AO_L_1E_BHK8K8k5pu8Fmg2" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/serenity/Serenity.CoreLib.js?v=1L8198NTwiEN0tbBJm4szw2" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/serenity/Serenity.Script.UI.js?v=FGT2MLhQAFXM0w_Ybxe0AQ2" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.cropzoom.js?v=ju9wbWcKr48aWqD5qkXCcQ2" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.fileupload.js?v=e-hGpVezhrzCNo0tj4bR2A2" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.iframe-transport.js?v=mCjCNWoMY71LgLOhwmmOGQ2" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.maskedinput.js?v=HN6v6EEgtiHc2VNZKpTJmA2" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.slimscroll.js?v=buWrXYmFe-bq8Itj6zJGsA2" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="/Scripts/SlickGrid/Plugins/slick.rowselectionmodel.js?v=XribFqTCdkXWmUfvTfmwMw2" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="/Scripts/mousetrap.js?v=LZ3oO7G3uh_XrsUxuoHUpA2" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="/Scripts/fastclick/fastclick.js?v=bp07DadPKkpwQrSUzap8Lg2" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="/Scripts/adminlte/app.js?v=sEFfHWOWYAV53y-2WWKVgw2" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="/Scripts/Site/Serene5.Web.js?v=MWzcm5FC-dWRLpEqVuzDwg2" type="text/javascript"></script>


<script src="/DynJS.axd/LocalText.Site.en-US.Public.js?v=TAg9qLhz34DPI6z4guBgog2"></script>
<script src="/DynJS.axd/ColumnsBundle.js?v=t0XeZZg0HS5LnLTkazC9fw2"></script>
<script src="/DynJS.axd/FormBundle.js?v=F99UAnyx4Xtee88SQxRi1A2"></script>
<script src="/DynJS.axd/TemplateBundle.js?v=q6ePJcfaBGdWeEuYVsIJHA2"></script>
<script src="/DynJS.axd/RegisteredScripts.js?v=c25aIR1HyiCXuBpDAHMSdQ2"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/iCheck/flat/blue.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/Scripts/morris/morris.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/Scripts/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap-1.2.2.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/Scripts/datepicker/datepicker3.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/Scripts/daterangepicker/daterangepicker-bs3.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/Scripts/bootstrap-wysihtml5/bootstrap3-wysihtml5.min.css">
<script src="/Scripts/raphael/raphael-min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/morris/morris.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/sparkline/jquery.sparkline.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap-1.2.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap-world-mill-en.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/knob/jquery.knob.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/daterangepicker/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/bootstrap-wysihtml5/bootstrap3-wysihtml5.all.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/adminlte/pages/dashboard.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/adminlte/demo.js"></script>

    <title>Dashboard - Serene5</title>
</head>
<body id="s-DashboardPage" class="fixed sidebar-mini hold-transition skin-blue has-layout-event">

<div class="wrapper">
    <header class="main-header">
        <a href="/" class="logo">
            <span class="logo-mini"><i></i></span>
            <span class="logo-lg"><i></i><b>Serene5</b></span>
        </a>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
            <a href="#" class="sidebar-toggle" data-toggle="offcanvas" role="button">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            </a>

            <div class="navbar-custom-menu">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="dropdown user user-menu">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                            <img src="/Content/adminlte/img/avatar04.png" class="user-image" alt="User Image">
                            <span class="hidden-xs">admin</span>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <!-- User image -->
                            <li class="user-header">
                                <img src="/Content/adminlte/img/avatar04.png" class="img-circle" alt="User Image">

                                <p>
                                    admin
                                </p>
                            </li>

                            <!-- Menu Footer-->
                            <li class="user-footer">
                                <div class="pull-left">
                                    <a href="/Account/ChangePassword" class="btn btn-default btn-flat"><i class="fa fa-lock fa-fw"></i> Change Password</a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="pull-right">
                                    <a href="/Account/Signout" class="btn btn-default btn-flat"><i class="fa fa-sign-out fa-fw"></i> Logout</a>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <a href="#" data-toggle="control-sidebar"><i class="fa fa-gears"></i></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <aside class="main-sidebar">
        <section class="sidebar">
            <form action="#" method="get" class="sidebar-form">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" id="SidebarSearch" name="q" class="form-control" autocomplete="off">
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button type="button" name="search" id="search-btn" class="btn btn-flat"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </form>
            <ul class="sidebar-menu" id="SidebarMenu">


<li class="active">
    <a href="/">
        <i class="nav-icon fa icon-speedometer"></i>
        <span>Dashboard</span>
    </a>

</li>
<li class=" treeview">
    <a href="javascript:;">
        <i class="nav-icon fa icon-screen-desktop"></i>
        <span>Administration</span>
        <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
    </a>

        <ul class="treeview-menu">

<li class="">
    <a href="/errorlog.axd"_blank target=_blank>
        <i class="nav-icon fa icon-ban"></i>
        <span>Exceptions Log</span>
    </a>

</li>
<li class="">
    <a href="/Administration/Language">
        <i class="nav-icon fa icon-bubbles"></i>
        <span>Languages</span>
    </a>

</li>
<li class="">
    <a href="/Administration/Translation">
        <i class="nav-icon fa icon-speech"></i>
        <span>Translations</span>
    </a>

</li>
<li class="">
    <a href="/Administration/Role">
        <i class="nav-icon fa icon-lock"></i>
        <span>Roles</span>
    </a>

</li>
<li class="">
    <a href="/Administration/User">
        <i class="nav-icon fa icon-people"></i>
        <span>User Management</span>
    </a>

</li>
        </ul>
</li>
<li class=" treeview">
    <a href="javascript:;">
        <i class="nav-icon fa icon-layers"></i>
        <span>Default</span>
        <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
    </a>

        <ul class="treeview-menu">

<li class="">
    <a href="/Default/TcpDump">
        <i class="nav-icon fa fa-circle-o"></i>
        <span>TcpDump</span>
    </a>

</li>
<li class="">
    <a href="/Default/Errors">
        <i class="nav-icon fa fa-circle-o"></i>
        <span>Errors</span>
    </a>

</li>
<li class="">
    <a href="/Default/Regeln">
        <i class="nav-icon fa fa-circle-o"></i>
        <span>Regeln</span>
    </a>

</li>
        </ul>
</li>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function openWindow(url, width, height) {
        height = height || (screen.availHeight - 60);
        width = width || (screen.availWidth - 10);
        var x = (screen.availWidth - width) / 2 - 5; if (x < 0) x = 0;
        var y = (screen.availHeight - height) / 2 - 25; if (y < 0) y = 0;
        var winPopup = window.open(url, "", "status=0, toolbar=0, width=" + width + ", height=" + height + 
            ", scrollbars=1, resizable=yes, left=" + x + ", top=" + y);
    }
</script>
            </ul>
        </section>
    </aside>

    <div class="content-wrapper">
        <section class="content-header">

    <h1>Dashboard<small>a sample with random data (from free <em><a href = "https://almsaeedstudio.com/" target= "_blank">AdminLTE theme</a></em>)</small></h1>

        </section>
        <section class="content">




<div class="row">
    <!-- Small boxes (Stat box) -->
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-6">
                <!-- small box -->
                <!-- achtung hier soll man vielleicht die Adresse ändern -->



                <div class="small-box bg-blue">
                    <div class="inner">
                        <h3>Station</h3>
                        <p> Station1</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="icon">
                        <i class="ion ion-stats-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </div>
                    <a href=Station1 class="small-box-footer">More info <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>
                </div>;

            </div>
        <!-- /.row -->
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-6">
                <!-- small box -->
                <!-- achtung hier soll man vielleicht die Adresse ändern -->



                <div class="small-box bg-black">
                    <div class="inner">
                        <h3>Station</h3>
                        <p> Station2</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="icon">
                        <i class="ion ion-stats-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </div>
                    <a href=Station2 class="small-box-footer">More info <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>
                </div>;

            </div>
        <!-- /.row -->
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-6">
                <!-- small box -->
                <!-- achtung hier soll man vielleicht die Adresse ändern -->



                <div class="small-box bg-green">
                    <div class="inner">
                        <h3>Station</h3>
                        <p> Station3</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="icon">
                        <i class="ion ion-stats-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </div>
                    <a href=Station3 class="small-box-footer">More info <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>
                </div>;

            </div>
        <!-- /.row -->

</div>
<!-- Main row -->
<div class="row">
    <!-- Left col -->
    <section class="col-lg-7 connectedSortable">
        <!-- Custom tabs (Charts with tabs)-->
        <div class="nav-tabs-custom">
            <!-- Tabs within a box -->
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs pull-right">
                <li class="active"><a href="#revenue-chart" data-toggle="tab">Area</a></li>
                <li><a href="#sales-chart" data-toggle="tab">Donut</a></li>
                <li class="pull-left header"><i class="fa fa-inbox"></i> Sales</li>
            </ul>
            <div class="tab-content no-padding">
                <!-- Morris chart - Sales -->
                <div class="chart tab-pane active" id="revenue-chart" style="position: relative; height: 300px;"></div>
                <div class="chart tab-pane" id="sales-chart" style="position: relative; height: 300px;"></div>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /.nav-tabs-custom -->
    </section><!-- right col -->
</div><!-- /.row (main row) -->

        </section>
    </div>

    <footer class="main-footer">
        <div class="pull-right hidden-xs">
            Serenity Platform
        </div>
        <strong>Copyright (c) 2015.</strong> All rights reserved.
    </footer>

    <aside class="control-sidebar control-sidebar-dark">
        <div class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane active" id="control-sidebar-settings-tab">
                <form method="post">
                    <h3 class="control-sidebar-heading">General Settings</h3>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-sidebar-subheading">Language</label>
                        <select id="LanguageSelect" class="form-control"></select>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group" style="margin-top: 15px;">
                        <label class="control-sidebar-subheading">Theme</label>
                        <select id="ThemeSelect" class="form-control"></select>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </aside>
    <div class="control-sidebar-bg"></div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $().ready(function () {
        new Serene5.Common.SidebarSearch($('#SidebarSearch'), $('#SidebarMenu')).init();
        new Serene5.Common.LanguageSelection($('#LanguageSelect'), 'en-US');
        new Serene5.Common.ThemeSelection($('#ThemeSelect'));
        ;

        var doLayout = function () {
            height = (this.window.innerHeight > 0) ? this.window.innerHeight : this.screen.height;
            height -= $('header.main-header').outerHeight() || 0;
            height -= $('section.content-header').outerHeight() || 0;
            height -= $('footer.main-footer').outerHeight() || 0;
            if (height < 200) height = 200;
            $("section.content").css("min-height", (height) + "px");

            $('body').triggerHandler('layout');
        };

        $(window).bind("load resize layout", doLayout);
        doLayout();
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

note : Here is an excerpt of the debug console

```
"iisexpress.exe" (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): "C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll" geladen. Das Laden von Symbolen wurde übersprungen. Das Modul ist optimiert, und die Debugoption "Nur eigenen Code" ist aktiviert.
"iisexpress.exe" (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): "C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Web\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.dll" geladen. Das Laden von Symbolen wurde übersprungen. Das Modul ist optimiert, und die Debugoption "Nur eigenen Code" ist aktiviert.
"iisexpress.exe" (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): "C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll" geladen. Das Laden von Symbolen wurde übersprungen. Das Modul ist optimiert, und die Debugoption "Nur eigenen Code" ist aktiviert.
```

(Sorry for german). "Das Laden von Symbolen wurde übersprungen" means "the load of symbols has been skipped"

Comment: What path is the browser attempting to load this icons? Also, bundles.

Comment: How may I find this ? And what do you mean by "bundles" ?

Comment: Use Developer tools in browser to see what address the icons are being loaded from. For Bundles, see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn451436.aspx)

Comment: First inspect the elements in dev tools and check if any 404 errors are there in the console. Another possible reason is your icons coming from a `.woff2` file. if yes, you need to add the `mimeMap` to IIS or web.config.

Comment: add  
`<staticContent><remove fileExtension=".woff2" /><mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="application/font-woff2" /></staticContent>` inside the `<system.webServer>` section of your web.config and check

Comment: @DanielShillcock I edited my post and included the html code generated by the page

Comment: @adiga It's already there ^^

Comment: @DoeJowns any 404 erros in the dev tools' console?

Comment: @adiga ... Yes ! (I edited my post)

Comment: @DanielShillcock ok, I got it, I moved by mistake my "fonts" file in another file !

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the very first response, what is the path of your font-awesome font files?

They need to be in the same place as the font-awesome CSS file expects them to be.

To determine what path is being used, using Google Chrome, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> or use the options menu > More Tools > Developer Tools. Navigate to the Network tab and you will be able to see a row relating to loading the fonts resource as well as a Status code (404 not found, 200 good).